# How to change dokku PHP memory_limit?

Tags: php, dokku, buildpack

I am hosting a WP blog on dokku, but there are stability issues, I suspect memory so I want to increase memory available to PHP, specifically, to set custom `memory_limit` value.

I am running on dokku `v0.5.6`, and using `BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php#102`

To debug the PHP settings of my `blog` app I run

```
dokku run blog php -ini | grep memory_limit
#=> memory_limit => 128M => 128M
```

I have followed the suggestions in

1. [Heroku PHP ini documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings)
2. [Heroku PHP concurrency documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-concurrency)
3. [Dokku issue #1098](https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/1098)

Specifically:

1. made `.user.ini` with `memory_limit = 256M`
2. made `fmp_custom.ini` with content `php_value[memory_limit] = 256M`
3. made `php_custom.ini` with content `memory_limit = 256M`
4. made `Procfile` with `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-nginx -C nginx.conf -F fpm_custom.ini -i php_custom.ini`
5. I have even forked the heroku buildpack and made a `/conf/php/php.ini` with content `memory_limit = 256M`

Neither strategy has yielded the desired output of

```
dokku run blog php -ini | grep memory_limit
#=> memory_limit => 256M => 256M
```

What am I missing? I am doubtful that nothing has affected PHP init settings, perhaps I am debugging incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the custom settings are related to the current thread of the app server process. In other words, if you check the `phpInfo()` output you can see that your `php_custom.ini` works as expected:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/u4pe88pcpkwl6rm/2016-06-05_0.10.51.png?dl=0

but the `php -ini | grep memory_limit` is still show you 128MB, because the php call spawns a new thread, especially if you run another container of your app.

Comment: `phpInfo()` in root index did indeed show that using .user.ini with `memory_limit=256M` sets a "local" setting for all application.