# How to modify upload file size limits for a dokku wordpress app?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, dokku

I've created an app with [dokku-wordpress](https://github.com/dokku-community/dokku-wordpress) and deployed it succesfully to a dokku server.

I've added an .htaccess file with the following values

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 40M
php_value post_max_size 42M
```

but when app is deployed and I try to access it throws an internal server error, and in the logs ssh -t dokku@ logs  I found the following error

> /app/.htaccess: Invalid command 'php_value', perhaps misspelled or
>   defined by a module not included in the server configuration

how may I increase the upload file size limit? it defaults to 2Mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question [How to change dokku PHP memory_limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298727/how-to-change-dokku-php-memory-limit) led me to the right answer found in the [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-php-settings). And it works since dokku uses the same buildpacks as heroku and also the app generated by [dokku-wordpress](https://github.com/dokku-community/dokku-wordpress).

Just add a .user.ini file in the root of your app with the following contents

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M
post_max_size = 42M
```

and it will be picked up by the server.