# How can I increase the upload_max_filesize size of my dokku container from the the default 2M to about 20M

Tags: php, docker, devops, dokku

I currently cannot the php.ini file within my app which would have been an entry point for making such modification.

has anyone had to do this before?

Comment: Alternatively, You can try `ini_set` from PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ini-set.php

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this will mutate the configuration on the container. since it is containerized. or what do you think?

Comment: The config option is `upload_max_filesize`, not `file_max_upload` - beyond that `ini_set` at runtime won't work for `upload_max_filesize` because the request body has already been parsed by the time your PHP is executing.

Comment: You can use `ini_set` at the beggining of your PHP script.

Comment: This will not work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347590/how-to-modify-upload-file-size-limits-for-a-dokku-wordpress-app

Answer (score 3):

You can do it via native `dokku` commands:

`dokku nginx:set <app-name> client-max-body-size 25m`

Answer (score 0):

@all i found a solution that worked for me.

since I use nginx on my server. I was able to locate the following file

```
/home/dokku/${app-name}/nginx.conf
```

and then In the `locate` block, i added the following

```
locate {
...

client_max_body_size 25M
}
```

And this increased the max_upload_filesize to 25M.